# Could not run adb reverse: spawnSync sdkdir ENOENT

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am developing an android app using react native. When I run `react-native run-android` the build is successful but I get the following error:

> C:\map\development\learnreact\react-native\helloworld>react-native
>   run-android Starting JS server... Building and installing the app on
>   the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
>
> > Task :app:installDebug 03:46:26 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config 03:46:27 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on
> >     '988a5b324d47353950' : EOF hit. Read: -1 03:46:27 V/ddms: execute:
> >     returning Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'SM-G955F - 8.0.0' for
> >     app:debug 03:46:27 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto
> >     device '988a5b324d47353950' 03:46:27 D/Device: Uploading file onto
> >     device '988a5b324d47353950' 03:46:27 D/ddms: Reading file permision of
> >     C:\map\development\learnreact\react-native\helloworld\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
> >     as: rwx------ 03:46:27 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t
> >     "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk" 03:46:49 V/ddms: execute 'pm install
> >     -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '988a5b324d47353950' : EOF hit. Read: -1 03:46:49 V/ddms: execute: returning 03:46:49 V/ddms:
> >     execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk" 03:46:49 V/ddms:
> >     execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '988a5b324d47353950' :
> >     EOF hit. Read: -1 03:46:49 V/ddms: execute: returning Installed on 1
> >     device.
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 44s 28 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 27 up-to-date
>   Running
>   C:\Users\bheka\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools/platform-tools/adb
>   -s 988a5b324d47353950 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 Could not run adb reverse: spawnSync
>   C:\Users\bheka\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools/platform-tools/adb
>   ENOENT Starting the app on 988a5b324d47353950
>   (C:\Users\bheka\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools/platform-tools/adb
>   -s 988a5b324d47353950 shell am start -n com.helloworld/com.helloworld.MainActivity)...

I have checked the port as suggested on other question and that is not the source of the problem. Anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a fix. Since it was giving an ENOENT error, I had to add a folder and name it "platform-tools" and adb.exe in it inside the `C:\Users\bheka\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` directory so that it becomes `C:\Users\bheka\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\platform-tools\adb.exe` and it worked.

Comment: This challenge is so dumb but thankfully your solution worked! I have RN version 0.60.5, Windows 10 Enterprise V1809, OS Build 17763.678